# Is There A Way To List Google Workspace App Usage By Number Of Users Through Appscript or on Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

As the title suggests, i would like to have a count by how many users in my organization use example G-Mail, Sheets, Docs, Slides Etc.

Is there a way to achieve this on Appscript or Sheets?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Reports API: Users Usage Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users).

On apps script you can use the advanced services to use the API methods as shown on the Apps Script documentation for [Admin SDK Reports Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports).

This is an example code for `Generate user usage report`:

```js
/**
 * Generates a user usage report for this day last week as a spreadsheet. The
 * report includes the date, user, last login time, number of emails received,
 * and number of drive files created.
 */
function generateUserUsageReport() {
  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  var parameters = [
    'accounts:last_login_time',
    'gmail:num_emails_received',
    'drive:num_items_created'
  ];
  var rows = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
      parameters: parameters.join(','),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (page.warnings) {
      for (var i = 0; i < page.warnings.length; i++) {
        var warning = page.warnings[i];
        Logger.log(warning.message);
      }
    }
    var reports = page.usageReports;
    if (reports) {
      for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        var report = reports[i];
        var parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
        var row = [
          report.date,
          report.entity.userEmail,
          parameterValues['accounts:last_login_time'],
          parameterValues['gmail:num_emails_received'],
          parameterValues['drive:num_items_created']
        ];
        rows.push(row);
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('G Suite User Usage Report');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = ['Date', 'User', 'Last Login', 'Num Emails Received',
        'Num Drive Files Created'];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No results returned.');
  }
}

/**
 * Gets a map of parameter names to values from an array of parameter objects.
 * @param {Array} parameters An array of parameter objects.
 * @return {Object} A map from parameter names to their values.
 */
function getParameterValues(parameters) {
  return parameters.reduce(function(result, parameter) {
    var name = parameter.name;
    var value;
    if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.intValue;
    } else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.stringValue;
    } else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
      value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
    } else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.boolValue;
    }
    result[name] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

Then you will use the API method [Method: userUsageReport.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get)